# VLC RTP network-caching

Tags: caching, vlc, rtp, sdp

I am streaming from my android phone's camera to my computer using RTP. I am using VLC to receive the stream. I am also using a hand written .sdp file to view the stream in VLC. When I was doing this over RTSP I could uses the command line -> vlc "rtsp://224.1.1.1:8086" --network-caching=0 to remove the 1000ms caching that would remove the delay. So now I am using -> myTest.sdp --network-caching=0 but it seems to have no affect. I have tried increasing it to 10 seconds, still no affect. It also seems that if I lower the quality of the video it will have more of a delay. What do I need to do to remove any kind of caching / buffering and always just show the latest frame as it comes in?

Comment: Any clue in the console output?

Comment: There is also --sout-mux-caching=<> option to try

Comment: it seems to be working as expected now (using VLC v3.0.14 on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make VLC to have a delay less than 1 ms. So [switching to ffplay with this parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658873/how-to-minimize-the-delay-in-a-live-streaming-with-ffmpeg) solved the problem:

```
ffplay.exe rtsp://224.1.1.1:8086 -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -avioflags direct -fflags discardcorrupt
```