# FFmpeg/OpenCV force ignore input frame duration with rtsp?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp, live-streaming

I was experiencing a `~5 sec` delay when playing a rtsp stream from an IP camera. After a bunch of googling (especially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658873/how-to-minimize-the-delay-in-a-live-streaming-with-ffmpeg)), I reduced the delay to `~1 sec` using the following command:

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -framedrop -strict experimental \
       -probesize 32 -sync ext rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But when I tried `mplayer -benchmark` command from the same question, I found the delay immediately goes away (i.e. almost 0 delay).

In the man page of `mplayer`, it sais:

> -benchmark
>
> Prints some statistics on CPU usage and dropped frames at the end of playback.  Use in combination with -nosound and -vo null for benchmarking only the video codec.
>
> NOTE: With this option MPlayer will also **ignore frame duration** when playing only video (you can think of that as infinite fps).

I feel this "ignore frame duration" is the key to the question, but after a bunch of googling, I didn't find any flag related to this in `ffmpeg`. I'm wondering **how to force ignore input frame duration in `ffmpeg`**?

On the other hand, the reason I'm using `ffmpeg` is because I need to do image processing using `opencv`, while I found it seems to be using some part of `ffmpeg` under-the-hood when doing

```
cv.VideoCapture('rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

A solution that directly solves the problem in `opencv` would be even more appreciated. I did try reading the `VideoCapture` repeatedly in a separate thread, that didn't help.

---

*Some info about the RTSP stream*: h264, 1920x1080, 15fps, 1 key frame per 4s

*Some other solutions I tried*:

```
ffmpeg -r 99999 -i ...
# didn't work

mplayer ... -dumpstream
# it core dumped
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading frames using `VideoCapture()` in a separate thread should increase performance due to I/O latency reduction. The `read()` operation is blocking so the main program is stalled until a frame is read from the camera stream. By placing the frame reading into a seprate thread, we should be able to grab and show frames in parallel instead of relying on a single thread to grab frames in sequential order. Replace `src` with your RTSP stream link.

Another reason there could be a delay could be because your resolution is `1920x1080`. Before you show the frame, you could resize it which should give better performance.

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time

class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            time.sleep(.01)

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        cv2.imshow('frame', self.frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget()
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But resizing didn't help, and the 1 second delay did not disappear using threading. As mentioned above, I believe this delay is definitely related to frame duration hidden inside `ffmpeg` used by `opencv`, i.e. the `.read()` call. Since `.read()` themselves cannot be done in parallel, making something else parallel won't help a lot.